# handling xml responses from httpclient in javascript policy

Tags: apigee

I have a backend SOAP webservice which has two methods - getCustomerByPhoneNumber and getOrderByCustomerId. I have a requirement to build a apigee json endpoint to fetch the latest order of a customer which should take phone number as input.

This means, I will have to create an API endpoint and a resource pointing to the SOAP method getOrderByCustomerId. Build an internal callout proxy (preferably javascript policy and use httpClient proxy object) to call SOAP method getCustomerByPhoneNumber to get the customer id and pass on the customerId to the endpoint method getOrderByCustomerId.
My concern is - how to handle the SOAP response from the method getCustomerByPhoneNumber!? if its JSON, its very easy to write logic to read the values from javascript code.

How can I easily parse xml/soap response in javascript or convert xml to JSON in javascript to read the response like an object?

Or, as another alternative, should I convert all my SOAP method to REST methods and the wrapper cumulative method should call converted REST method (in the callout proxy) instead of calling the SOAP method directly..

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

Apigee uses E4X which adds support for XML (see: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/javascript-object-model).  An example below demonstrates how you can work with a SOAP response.  This is something I quickly put together using an example soap message from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_example.asp).

**Example SOAP response message:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
  <soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
    <m:m:GetStockPriceResponse>
      <m:Price>34.5</m:Price>
    </m:m:GetStockPriceResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Example javascript in Apigee:**

```
var mockResponse ='<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding"><soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock"><m:GetStockPriceResponse><m:Price>34.5</m:Price></m:GetStockPriceResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

var soap = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope');
var m = new Namespace('http://www.example.org/stock');
var xmlObj = new XML (mockResponse);

var stockPrice = xmlObj.soap::Body.m::GetStockPriceResponse.m::Price;


response.content.status = 200;
response.content.status.message = 'OK';
response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/plain';
response.content = 'stockPrice: ' + stockPrice;
```

**Leaves you with a response like:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain
Content-Length: 16

stockPrice: 34.5
```